# Forecasting with use of PCA variables as independent and one ternary dependent variable in R

Tags: r, regression, pca, forecasting, vector-autoregression

I'm having trouble in taking a direction of my research project. I have independent variables that are commonly used as economic indicators and I want to include variables/indicators that are not commonly used to improve my eventual forecasts. I have 31 independent variables with 607 monthly observations after making it stationary and applying the scale function.(scale was applied cause my variable series are of different units/measures)
   I used the PCA function and got down to 13 components that capture 80% cumulative of the variance.
   Question is now that I have 13 new independent variables and the one dependent variable that is ternary in the sense that in the 607 observations it indicates 1 for peak, 0 for nothing, and -1 as trough, what model is best for forecasting/predicting the next 1 & -1 of my dependent variable series based on my 13 independent principal components?

FYI: I have looked at VAR, Cointegration, Granger Causality, Multiple Linear Regression, but can't really make sense if what I'm using is correct and appropriate for my topic.

Comment: When your dependent variable takes only three values, simple linear regression will not do (neither will VAR); they are suited for continuous responses. You could try a [multinomial logit model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) instead.